# View jumps using animateContentSize compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to animate a sheet like but the view keeps jumping when it collapse. Using a `BottomSheetScaffold` leads to the same issue (I saw that there is an issue open on Google bug tracker related to that)

Link to a video to demonstrate the issue : https://streamable.com/q1g3ej

Here is the code

```
@Composable
private fun BoxScope.Sheet() {
    var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val searchAddressInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isClicked by searchAddressInteractionSource.collectIsClickedAsState()

    if (isClicked) {
        isExpanded = true
    }

    val radius = if (isExpanded) 0.dp else 32.dp
    val animatedCornerRadius = animateDpAsState(targetValue = radius, label = "sheetCornerRadius")

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .animateContentSize()
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            .background(color = LocalColorScheme.current.grayscaleWhite, shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = animatedCornerRadius.value, topEnd = animatedCornerRadius.value))
            .padding(horizontal = 32.dp, vertical = 24.dp)
    ) {
        AnimatedContent(
            targetState = isExpanded,
            transitionSpec = { fadeIn() togetherWith fadeOut() },
            label = "SheetContent"
        ) { isSheetExpanded ->
            if (isSheetExpanded) {
                SearchAddress(
                    searches = emptyList(),
                    onCloseClicked = { isExpanded = false }
                )
            } else {
                SaveFavorite(
                    searchAddressInteractionSource = searchAddressInteractionSource
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the sheet sticky to the bottom.

`Sheet` composable is also wrapped inside an other box to have buttons at the top being overlapped

Do you know could I fix this ? I think I need to manage the height manually but don't really know how to

Thanks !

Comment: You wrote that you found the issue on the Google Issue Tracker. What is written there? Can you link the issue here?